# Spinner while loading image for twitter bootstrap thumbnails?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, thumbnails, scaling, font-awesome

We are dynamically generating thumbnails when the user clips out a section of a video via PHP.

To do this when the section is clipped we send off via ajax to the server some information, it calls ffmpeg to generate the thumbnails, it then eventually gets back to us when the thumbnail is generated so we can display this below the video clipper using twitter bootstrap's thumbnails.

Here is a basic example of what the user sees while we wait for a thumbnail: http://jsfiddle.net/Rnt9N/2/

Obviously not good, it looks messy. so what we want is for the spinner to be centered both horizontally and vertically, and also for it to scale (since the thumbnails are responsive, we need the spinner to be able to grow).

It's just basic htmt, but apprently I need to include code here:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <i class="icon icon-spin icon-spinner"></i>
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                </a>

            </li>
            <li class="span2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
                </a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```